# How to count based on a simple equation in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am wondering how it would be possible to return a number based on `count` depending on the field value in MySQL.

So let's say you had a simple MySQL setup like:

```
Users (id)
Posts (id, user_id, body)
Votes (id, post_id, user_id, vote_type)
```

And then you wanted to get the top 10 posts, ordered by how many MORE records where `vote_type='up'` than `vote_type='down'`

```
SELECT votes.*, ((SELECT count(post_id) FROM votes AS v1 WHERE vote='up' 
AND votes.post_id =v1.post_id) - (SELECT count(post_id) FROM votes AS v2 
WHERE vote='down' AND votes.post_id =v2.post_id)) AS score FROM votes GROUP 
BY votes.post_id ORDER BY score DESC
```

The above query works, however it would not account for posts where there are no post votes, and also seems like there could be a better way.

Comment: Add some sample data and what should be the desired result based on the sample you provided.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT
  posts.*, (a.up_count - b.down_count) as net_vote
FROM
  posts
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    post_id, COUNT(*) as up_count
  FROM
    votes
  WHERE
    vote_type = 'up'
  GROUP BY
    post_id
) a ON a.post_id = posts.id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    post_id, COUNT(*) as down_count
  FROM
    votes
  WHERE
    vote_type = 'down'
  GROUP BY
    post_id
) b ON b.post_id = posts.id
ORDER BY
  net_vote DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Hmm. I am receiving an `Unknown column 'vote_type' in 'having clause' error`

Comment: @space_food_ changed it to use `where`

Answer (score 0):

You could use some  join

```
    SELECT votes.*, ifnull(v1.count,0) - innull(v2.count,0) AS score
    FROM votes
    LEFT  JOIN ( 
        SELECT post_id, count(post_id) as count
        FROM votes AS v1 WHERE vote='up' 
        GROUP BY post_id ) v1 on votes.post_id = v1.post_id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT post_id, count(post_id) 
        FROM votes AS v1 WHERE vote='down' 
        GROUP BY post_id ) v2  on votes.post_id = v2.post_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select p.*
from posts p
left join votes v on v.post_id = p.id
group by 1, 2, 3
order by sum(vote_type = 'down') - sum(vote_type = 'up')
limit 10
```

Note the simple way to count up how many times a contortion is true; in MySQL true is 1 and false is 0, so we can sum the condition.

If you also want to see what the difference in vote type counts is, add the order by expression to the select list.

Comment: This is a very simple solution, thanks. How will it know what to group by for 1, 2, and 3?

Comment: 1,2 and 3 are the numbers of the columns you selected. This list of numbers needs to be the same length as the actual number of columns in `posts`. You can alternatively name the columns, ie `group by id, user_id, body`. I prefer the brevity. Whichever way you chose it is important that the columns select and grouped by match.